# How to Move image in SurfaceView from top to bottom only

Tags: android, image, bitmap, surfaceview

I was wondering that someone help me that how can i implement the bug Smasher simple function, 
I want to move image from top to bottom and want to change the image whn someone click on the image, just like Bug Smasher Game. I have idea of SurfaceView n able to draw Image on the SurfaceView.

Code, Sample?

Please Help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Give more information and code how ou are moving the images please. Maybe this little example of one of my projects will help you.

```
float x = 0,y = -1;
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) 
{
   float delta = 0;
   long currentFrameStart = System.nanoTime();
   if(lastFrame!=0)
      delta = (currentFrameStart-lastFrame) / 1000000000.0f;
   lastFrame = currentFrameStart; 

   antTexture.bind();

   gl.glPushMatrix();

   y += delta*0.1f;
   gl.glTranslatef(x, y, 0 ); 
   //gl.glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1);

   antMesh.render(PrimitiveType.TriangleFan, 0, 4);

   gl.glPopMatrix(); 
}
```

I implemented a minigame version of Ant Smasher in my game Orc Genocide

[image]